# What is the rule of Gift "ElHiba" in Islam?

Tags: halal-haram, sunnah, islamic-philosophy

There is no talk about the gift "Elhiba" on koran  and there is a talk in Hadith , but for example a person has two children gives them a gift of money or Houses and gives the first more than the second, is considered injustice in Islam?
 Is it permissible to give?

Answer (score 2):

The following hadith is relevant:

> عن النعمان بن بشير قال تصدق علي أبي ببعض ماله فقالت أمي عمرة بنت رواحة لا أرضى حتى تشهد رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم فانطلق أبي إلى النبي صلى الله عليه وسلم ليشهده على صدقتي فقال له رسول الله صلى الله عليه وسلم أفعلت هذا بولدك كلهم قال لا قال اتقوا الله واعدلوا في أولادكم فرجع أبي فرد تلك الصدقة
>
> Nu'man b. Bashir reported:  My father donated to me some of his property.
>
> My mother Amra bint Rawaha said: I shall not be pleased (with this act) until you make Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) a witness to it. My father went to Allah's Apostle (ﷺ) in order to make him the witness of the donation given to me.
>
> Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said to him: Have you done the same with every son of yours?
>
> He said: No.
>
> Thereupon he (the Holy Prophet) said: Fear Allah, and observe equity in case of your children. My father returned and got back the gift.
>
> <sup>— [Muslim](http://sunnah.com/muslim/24/19) and [Bukhari](http://sunnah.com/bukhari/51/21)</sup>

There are variants of this hadith mentioned in [Sahih Muslim](https://sunnah.com/muslim/24) under:

باب كراهة تفضيل بعض الاولاد في الهبة

(Chapter: It Is Disliked To Favor Some Of One's Children Over
Others In Gift-Giving)

Some include the saying of the Prophet:

> فارجعه or  فاردده
>
> Take it back

and

> لا أشهد على جور
>
> I do not bear witness to an injustice

The schools differ on whether the action is *makruh* or *haram*:

> فمذهب الشافعي ومالك وأبي حنيفة أنه مكروه وليس بحرام ، والهبة صحيحة ، وقال طاوس وعروة ومجاهد والثوري وأحمد وإسحاق وداود : هو حرام ، واحتجوا برواية : ( لا أشهد على جور ) وبغيرها من ألفاظ الحديث واحتج الشافعي وموافقوه بقوله صلى الله عليه وسلم : ( فأشهد على هذا غيري ) ـ
>
> The madhab of Shafi, Malik and Abu Hanifa is that it is *makruh* and not *haram*, although the gift will be valid. And Tawus, Urwah, Mujahid, Thawri, Ahmad ibn Hanbal and Daud's view is that it is haram, and their evidence is the narration with the wording "*I do not bear witness over injustice*" and the evidence of Shafi and those who share his opinion is the narration with the wording "*Make someone else a witness to it*"
>
> <sup>—  [Sharah Nawawi](https://islamweb.net/ar/library/index.php?page=bookcontents&ID=4961&bk_no=53&flag=1)</sup>